# Restsharp Deserializer returns empty properties of Array of Objects

Tags: c#, json, restsharp, json-deserialization

I'm returning a JSON containing an array of objects from an API I made. 
`[{"Beneficiary":"QaiTS","Total":1000.00,"CurrencyCode":"PHP"},      {"Beneficiary":"MANILEÑOS","Total":4500.00,"CurrencyCode":"PHP"}]`

I'm trying to deserialize it with Restsharp's deserializer but when I print out the list, it shows that the properties are empty.

Here's how my code looks like:

```
    var client = new RestClient("http://localhost:4000/api/payments/GetPaymentSummary");
        var request = new RestRequest(Method.GET);
        request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;

        var response = client.Execute<List<PaymentSummary>>(request);
        JsonDeserializer deserialize = new JsonDeserializer();
        List<PaymentSummary> list = deserialize.Deserialize<List<PaymentSummary>>(response);
```

Result when I print it on output:

```
   Beneficiary: 
   CurrencyCode: 
   Total: 0
   Beneficiary: 
   CurrencyCode: 
   Total: 0
```

EDIT: this is what the PaymentSummary class looks like:

```
    public class PaymentSummary
       {
           public string Beneficiary;
           public decimal Total;
           public string CurrencyCode;
       }
```

Comment: What is the definition of `PaymentSummary`?

Comment: updated my question :)

Comment: Try two things: 1) make the fields in `PaymentSummary` properties, and 2) use `IEnumerable` instead of `List`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your class is currently composed of public fields.  RestSharp does not deserialize to fields, only public properties.  You need to update it to the following:

```
public class PaymentSummary
{
    public string Beneficiary { get; set; }
    public decimal Total { get; set; }
    public string CurrencyCode { get; set; }
}
```